# Functionals on the space of compactly supported smooth functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$, we define a functional $\phi_f(g)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} fg dx$ on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $D$ be the differentiation operation on $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

How to prove that $D'\phi_f = \phi_{-Df}$?
How to show that if $D'\phi = 0$ then $\phi = \phi_{c}$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: What does it mean $D'\phi_f$, is it supposed to be the map $g \mapsto \int_R f(x) g'(x)dx$  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\phi_{-Df}(g)=\int_\mathbb{R}-Dfgdx=\int_\mathbb{R}D(fg)dx-\int_\mathbb{R}Dfgdx=$

$=\int_\mathbb{R}fD(g)dx=\phi_f(Dg)$

While if $D’\phi_f=0$ then

$\phi_{-Df}(g)=-\int_\mathbb{R}D(f)gdx=0$

for each $g$

In general when you have a $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ function $h$ such that

$\int_\mathbb{R}hgdx=0$ for each $g$ then

$h=0$

In fact you can choose $g=h$ to have

$\int_\mathbb{R}h^2dx=0$ that implies $h=0$

So in your case $D(f)=0$ that means $f=c$

You can observe that $c=0$ because $f$ is continuos with compact support.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get from the first integral to the second one?

Comment: @yunadesu is the formula of integration by parts

Comment: oh sorry I meant the second step

Comment: @yunadesu ah, I use the fact that g has compact support to say that \int_R D(fg)dx=lim_{x\to \infty}fg -\lim_{x\to-\infty}fg=0

Comment: Got it Thank you!

Comment: FedericoFallucca Your part about $f'=0 \implies f=c$ is quite sloppy. Let $\phi \in C^\infty_c, \int \phi=1,c=\int f \phi$, for $g \in C^\infty_c$ let $A = \int g$ and $h(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x (g(y)-A\phi(y))dy$ **then** $h\in C^\infty_c$ so that $f' =0 \implies \int f(g-A\phi)= \int f \phi' = -\int f' \phi=0$ thus $\int fg = A \int f\phi = Ac=\int cg$ @yunadesu

Comment: Thank you, how did you get the equality from $f’=0$ though?